# sed/awk/perl: find a regex, copy 5 columns of this line and paste to it at the beginning of the next lines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, text-processing

### I have following lines:

```
057         -   -   No    adod3 stptazlqn    10    753
tlm    10    027        
stp    10    021                
12         -   -   No    azad1
bbcz     30    12        
03085         -   -   No    azad1 azad1222
xxaz    1    12        
azzst    1    12        
hss     2    12
```

### what I need to do is:

1. Find lines starting with a number [0-9].
2. Copy the first 5 columns separated by a space ' '.
3. Paste it in the next lines not starting with a number.

> ```
> 057         -   -   No    adod3 stptazlqn    10    753
> 057         -   -   No    adod3     tlm    10    027        
> 057         -   -   No    adod3     stp    10    021                
> 12         -   -   No    azad1
> 12         -   -   No    azad1    bbcz     30    12        
> 03085         -   -   No    azad1 azad1222
> 03085         -   -   No    azad1    xxaz    1    12        
> 03085         -   -   No    azad1    azzst    1    12        
> 03085         -   -   No    azad1    hss     2    12
> ```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Cheers,
Slaw

Comment: what have you tried so far? Ask us for specific problem, Not your whole code.

Comment: the lines starting with a number where split in two, I was able to fix it by using sed ':a $!N;s/\n[a-z]/ /;ta P;D' /tmp/test1 | sed '/^$/d' and now I'm bashing my head against the wall - don't know what to do next that's why I decided to ask for your help.

Comment: When you get a line starting with a number, save the values that you want to  copy into variables. Then use those variables when you're processing lines that don't start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{if($1+0==$1) p=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5; else $0=p FS $0}1' file | column -t

057    -  -  No  adod3  stptazlqn  10  753
057    -  -  No  adod3  tlm        10  027
057    -  -  No  adod3  stp        10  021
12     -  -  No  azad1
12     -  -  No  azad1  bbcz       30  12
03085  -  -  No  azad1  azad1222
03085  -  -  No  azad1  xxaz       1   12
03085  -  -  No  azad1  azzst      1   12
03085  -  -  No  azad1  hss        2   12
```

here `FS` is the field separator by default is the white space.  Number test is done with zero addition; pipe to `column` for pretty formatting. The `1` at the end is the shorthand for printing the line (`$0` variable)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]/!G;s/(.*\S)\s*\n((\S+\s*){5}).*/\2 \1/;h' file
```

Use pattern matching to extract the fields from line beginning with an integer which will have been appended to a line that did not.

To align the columns correctly use:

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]/!G;s/(.*\S)\s*\n((\S+\s*){5}).*/\2 \1/;h' file | column -t
```